# How to generate url based saas per tenant?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, saas

I have built ReactJS web application with authentication, stripe payment integration, subscription maintenance modules.

Now, I want to build dynamic urls (frontend questionnaire and questionnaire admin) for each customer upon payment successful.

Currently my app is deployed on Google cloud run with front end  url looks like https://<frontendapp.com>, and admin url looks like https://<adminapp.com>,

1. How to build an url for each subscribed customer ?. Should I go  for https://customername.frontendapp.com or just use one url https://frontendapp.com and send query string tenant id or customer id to this url?
2. If I have to use first url (subdomain) approach, how to provision each instance either in cloud run or appengine through code, ? is there any code sample available?
3. If  I have to use one url, how to pass the query string tenant id or customer id and filter the record?

Assumptions:

1. I will use one database with tenant_id as the key
2. Questions json are stored in cloud SQL (Postgres)
3. Answers are stored in Google BigQuery

Thanks,